# How can I wait for complete execution of For loop and then run next code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

```
var token = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= offlineMembers.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(offlineMembers[i]) === 'string') {
        ddb.get({
            TableName: "DB",
            Key: {
                Username: offlineMembers[i]
            }
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err || Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                token.push(data.Item.token)
            }
        })
    }
}
console.log(token)
```

This is my code.

It always logs out the token array as empty [].

How can I wait for the execution of for loop to end and then run the console.log command?

Comment: Do you know how to use `async`/`await`? Or have you heard of it at least?

Comment: See if your 'ddb' library supports promises and learn about async/await. If it doesn't support promises, you can convert it with `util.promisify` but most modern libraries have promise support

Comment: @kelly Yes, I am aware of async await I tried it but that works for DB calls. What about the loop? I am not sure how can you use it for a loop

Comment: @Evert I am using DynamoDB and it supports promises but I am not sure how come that will help in waiting for the loop to execute fully and then console log

Comment: @Nishanktiwari17 It should work as long as you keep using a regular for/loop and the outer function is defined as async.

Comment: @FirminoChangani Can you please help me understand it by updating this code

Comment: You can have a look at this [guide](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/) on how to use `async/await` in loops

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to accomplish this (as mentioned in most comments).

**Example:**

```js
let populateToken = (async () => {
  const token = [];
  // For Loop
  return token;
 })
 
 const token = await populateToken();
 console.log(token);
```